# Flutter: log in with a different Facebook user

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-facebook-login, flutter-facebook-social-plugins

Using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth
flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.7

When I log out I run await `FacebookAuth.instance.logOut();` but despite of that, the user is always saved and I just have to click continue.

Log in works fine with `final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();`

Answer (score 0):

Not possible due to Facebook's policy:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/
"The Android and iOS SDKs don't currently support re-authentication."

Comment: not possible. Check my answer

Answer (score -1):

From their documentation, this is how you are supposed to do a clean logout.

```
Future<void> _logOut() async {
    await FacebookAuth.instance.logOut();
    _accessToken = null;
    _userData = null;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Make sure you set _accessToken and _userData to null